# Is it possible to delegatecall a function that calls a private function?

Tags: delegatecall, private, access

I don't think this is possible but I would just like to make sure. An example would be the following?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

contract Victim{

    ERC20 token;

    constructor(){
        //token = ...
    }

    function publicFun() public {
        require(...) // some checks
        privateFun();
    }

    function privateFun() private{
        token.transfer(msg.sender, 100);
    }
}

contract Attacker{

    function attack() public{
        Victim v = Victim(0x...);
        delegatecall("publicFun");
    }

}
```

Would calling the `attack` function in the `Attacker` contract be able to successfully run and transfer the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

No, delegatecall would run `publicFun` on the Attacker contract's storage.

Even in case it doesn't revert, it will not modify Victim contract's storage.